# Как сделать сортировку списка по определенным символам?

Tags: python, список

Есть список со названиями интерфейсов. Подскажите, как сделать сделать сортировку по номеру интерфейса?
Например, interface Tunnel 0, interface Tunnel 1, interface Tunnel 2 и так далее..

```
some_list = ['interface Tunnel 0' , 'interface Tunnel 10', 'interface Tunnel 5' , 'interface Tunnel 3', 'interface Tunnel 7' , 'interface Tunnel 23']
```

Просто сортировка через sort() выдает мне не тот результат:

```
['interface Tunnel 0', 'interface Tunnel 10', 'interface Tunnel 23', 'interface Tunnel 3', 'interface Tunnel 5', 'interface Tunnel 7']
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
some_list = ['interface Tunnel 0' , 'interface Tunnel 10', 'interface Tunnel 5' , 'interface Tunnel 3', 'interface Tunnel 7' , 'interface Tunnel 23']
res = sorted(some_list, key=lambda x: int(x.split()[-1]))
```

Результат:

```
['interface Tunnel 0',
 'interface Tunnel 3',
 'interface Tunnel 5',
 'interface Tunnel 7',
 'interface Tunnel 10',
 'interface Tunnel 23']
```

Answer (score 0):

Через метод sort передаем функцию в key (сортируем по последнему числу):

`some_list.sort(key=lambda x: int(x.split()[-1]))`

Если хотим вернуть этот список:

`print(sorted(some_list, key=lambda x: int(x.split()[-1])))`